# div scaled to zero width still taking up space

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, skrollr

The `div` in the middle here is not shown, but it is still taking up the width it would have taken up if the width was not scaled.  How can I have the middle `div` not take up any space but still use the scale transformation?  I do not want to use `display: none;`

```html
<style>
div {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 3em;
}
</style>

<div>Your</div>
<div style='transform: scale(0, 1);'>&nbsp;potential</div>
<div>&nbsp;house</div>
```

My ultimate goal is to use this with skrollr and gradually expand the div in the middle upon scrolling down:

```html
<style>
div {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 3em;
}
</style>

<div style='position: fixed;'>
  <div>Your</div>
  <div data-0='transform: scale(0, 1);' data-200='transform: scale(1, 1);'>&nbsp;potential</div>
  <div>&nbsp;house</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/0.6.30/src/skrollr.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var s = skrollr.init();
</script>
```

Using `font-size` instead of `transform` also expands the text in, but it's not the effect I want to achieve.

`inline` results in the div in the middle to always be displayed.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use inline instead of inline-block?

Answer (score -1):

Give `font-size:0` or `width:0` to remove space.

```html
<style>
div {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 3em;
}
</style>

<div>Your</div>
<div style='transform: scale(0, 1);font-size:0'>&nbsp;potential</div>
<div>&nbsp;house</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but then I might as well not use the transform.